# traefik proxy to frontend container with nuxt static app

Tags: docker, nginx, nuxt.js, devops, traefik

I have problem with showing my frontend (nuxt spa static app) on the client. On url `my.domain:8090` I can't view my frontend. You can see all source code on gistGithub [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/designervoid/424f6e1c14a982d210d39422e966f23c).
In traefik admin dashboard I see connection with with docker-compose `frontend_service`, but it is unavailable when I go to URL `my.domain:8090`, then I has an error with white screen and text on `bad gateway` with status `502`. How can I solve this problem?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by adding the label in docker-compose-frontend

```
"traefik.http.services.my_frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=8090"
```